# Unimportant branches are stuck at the top of my tig view

Tags: tig

I am using tig version 2.2.1, and for some reason tig decides to show me a couple of unimportant branches, in addition to the branch I am currently working on.

The two additional branches has nothing to do with my currently working branch, they were never merged to each other or anything like that.

When I use `git log --graph` everything seems perfectly fine, I can't understand what makes tig go haywire.

Answer (score 2):

Tig's main view which shows commits uses the currently checked out branch, but will show other branch names if those branches are a subset of the current branch's history. The associated `git-log` commit would be closer to:

```
git log --graph --decorate
```

It is possible to disabled the display of branch names by putting the following in `~/.tigrc`:

```
set main-view-commit-title-refs = false
```

Comment: and what if `git log --graph --decorate` differs from my default `tig` view dramatically? The first commit in `tig` has _nothing_ to do with the currently checked out branch, they are not related in any way.

Comment: For instance, I have my feature branch checked-out, but when I fire up tig I see commits in release branch (that are even older than commits in my feature branch) on top of the list, or even worse, I see others' feature branches that has _nothing_ to do with my feature branch. :-(